# ArgumentNull Exception: Parameter name: ServerConnection

Tags: wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I have implemented WCF service for the database synchronization of Microsoft Sync Framework since the databases are not on the same network.

However when I call Sychronize() method on my SyncOrchestrator I get an error ArgumentNull Exception: Parameter name: ServerConnection.

I am not sure what parameter I have missed in my SyncOrchestrator setup. I cannot find a good help on the internet either. Can you please advise what could be the wrong

Code follows:

```
SyncOperationStatistics status = null;

//Creating proxy and Local sqlsync Provider to create scope on remote based on Locle table description
SqlSyncProvider localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(localConnString), null, "sync");
PSHInternetSyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new PSHInternetSyncOrchestrator(localProvider, remoteProvider, syncTable);

//Setting up batch size
localProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = 4096;

status = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

Comment: What is a `PSHInternetSyncOrchestrator`?

Comment: It is a proxy class created on client end to access WCF service hosted on server.

Comment: Can you show the code of the orchestrator's `Synchronize()`-method?

Comment: This proxy is actually derives from framework's SyncOrchestrator class and .Synchronize() call is to main for the base SyncOrchestrator class.

Comment: Sorry I do not have my code on my laptop so cannot give you the exact detail but I will as soon as I have access to my offce computer.

Comment: I restructure my code and it seems to be working now. Still not sure what was wrong with my original code so cannot answer this thread.

Comment: why do you have a proxy for the syncorchestrator? are you initiating the sync from the server? typically, you would have a proxy for the remote provider.

Comment: Yes I have the proxy for the remote provider. The sync is being initiated from the client end. I had something else wrong in my code. I rewrote entirely as I mention in my previous comment and things are working properly.